# Proposition 1.11, Atiyah-Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I need help in this item:

*i)* Let $P_1,...,P_n$ be prime ideals and let $I$ be an ideal contained in $\bigcup P_i $. Then $I 
  \subseteq P_i$ for some $i$.

It is proved by induction on $n$ and using the contrapositive. If $n=1$, the result is certainly true. If $n>1$ and the result is true for $n-1$, then for each $i$ there exists $x_i \in I$ such that $x_i \notin P_j$ whenever $j \neq i$. If for some $i$ we have $x_i \notin p_i$ we are through.
(My ploblem is in the other case). If not, then $x_i \in P_i$ for all $i$. Consider the element
$$y=\sum_{i=1}^n x_1x_2...x_{i-1}x_{i+1}x_{i+2}...x_n;$$
Why do we have that $y \notin P_i$, for each $1\leq i \leq n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty clear. So $x_i \in P_i$ for any $i$ and $x_i \notin P_j$ if $i \neq j$. Consider $$y = \sum_{k=1}^n x_1 \ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}\ldots x_n$$
Clearly $x_1 \ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}\ldots x_n \in P_i$ if $k \neq i$. Hence $y \notin P_i \iff x_1 \ldots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\ldots x_n \notin P_i$. If this product would belong to $P_i$ then $(\exists) j \neq i$ such that $x_j \in P_i$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $y\in P_i$ for some $i$, then write $$y=a_1+\cdots+ a_n.$$

Then for $j\neq i$, since $x_i$ appears in $a_j$ as a factor, $a_j\in P_i$.

Hence $a_i= x_1\cdots x_{i-1}\cdot x_{i+1}\cdots x_n\in P_i$. Thus, $x_j\in P_i$ for some $j\neq i.$

But that is a contradiction to the construction of $x_i$'s.